# Somar duas colunas e subtrair com condição

Tags: sql, sqlite

Estou tentando somar duas colunas depois subtrair da seguinte forma no sql:

```
SELECT sum(valor) WHERE lancamentotipo = "R" - sum(valor) WHERE lancamentotipo = "D" from lancamentos
```

Da forma acima adicionando uma clausula "WHERE" recebo erro porem se eu faço da seguinte forma funciona:

```
SELECT sum(valor) - sum(valor2) from lancamentos
```

Como faço para inserir uma clausula "WHERE" corretamente no caso acima, pois tenho certeza que estou errando em algo simples, pois quero somar e subtrair valores de uma mesma tabela com determinada condição.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN lancamentotipo = "R" THEN valor WHEN lancamentotipo = "D" THEN -valor ELSE 0 END) AS resultado FROM lancamentos;
```

Caso "R" e "D" seja os únicos valores possíveis que `lancamentotipo` possa assumir então basta substituir a segunda cláusula `WNEN` por um `ELSE`.